# Mplab XC16: can't use sprintf to convert float to string

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip, mplab, xc16

I want to use sprintf function to convert a float to string, here is part of the main.c code : (PIC24JF64GA004)

```
double VLine1Float; 
char LCDBuffer[4]; 
VLine1Float = 3.33;  
sprintf(LCDBuffer,"%1.2f",VLine1Float);
```

it is compiled with no errors, but when I run it, it gets stuck at the sprintf function and does nothing except executing interrupts routines.

The function work normally with unsigned integer to string conversion, with both %u and %x specifiers

I tried everything but it just doesn't work with float.
I just want to add that I used it in the past with xc8 and it worked

Any one can help ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a pure programming question with no microcontroller-specific or electronic-related aspects. It belongs on https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I wrote a short beginner FAQ regarding strings here: [Common string handling pitfalls in C programming](https://software.codidact.com/posts/284849). Yours is bug #2 in the FAQ.

Comment: A C string needs an extra NULL terminator byte on the end of the string, so your 4 character string needs a 5 byte array to hold it.

Answer (score 1):

The array is not long enough to contain the string.